# Django Admin: has_delete_permission

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to implement a prohibition on removing the last ingredient from a recipe. So that the recipe is not left empty without ingredients, or make the recipe deleted when the last ingredient is deleted.

model

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='recipes',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
    )
    text = models.TextField(
    )
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='recipes/'
    )
    cooking_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=(
            MinValueValidator(
                MIN_VALUE
            ),
            MaxValueValidator(
                MAX_VALUE
            ),
        )
    )
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredient,
        related_name='recipes',
        through='IngredientRecipe'
    )
```

admin

```
class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',
                    'author',
                    )
    list_filter = ('name', 'author',
                   ('tags', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter),)
    inlines = (IngredientRecipeInline, TagRecipeInline)

class IngredientRecipeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IngredientRecipe
    min_num = 1

class IngredientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',
                    'measurement_unit',
                    )

class IngredientRecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('recipe',
                    'ingredient',
                    'amount',
                    )
    list_filter = ('ingredient',)
```

i try min_num = 1 but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If you want ***prohibition on removing*** the last ingredient from a recipe:

But it will not work if you initially choose all **IngredientRecipe** objects to delete because this method just disable delete button for Inline objects

```
class IngredientRecipeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = IngredientRecipe

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):    
        if obj and obj.recipes.ingredients.count() == 1:
            return False
        return super().has_delete_permission(request, obj)
```

or if you want make the ***recipe deleted*** when the last ingredient is deleted, you can do something like this:

```
class IngredientRecipe(models.Model):

    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        if self.recipes.ingredients.count()==1:
            self.recipes.delete()
        super().delete(using, keep_parents)
```

Comment: I have a server error (500) in django admin panel

Comment: what type of error did you face?

Comment: 'none type' object has no attribute 'ingredients'
in def has_delete_permission for string if obj.ingredients.count() == 1:

Comment: Ah, i see, I updated my answer. Please check this one and please pay attention on prohibition on removing text